# Return different rows for each column in a row

Tags: sql

I have data which is presented in multiple rows and columns with 0 or 1 values. What I'm trying to do is create a unique row for each 1, but there are sometimes multiple 1's in a row. For ex:

```
**A    B    C    D**
  1    0    1    1
  0    0    0    1
  1    1    0    0
```

I would like to have return six rows, all in one column like so

```
**RETURN**
     A
     C
     D
     D
     A
     B
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `union all` statement:

```
select val
from ((select 'A' as val from t where A = 1) union all
      (select 'B' from t where B = 1) union all
      (select 'C' from t where C = 1) union all
      (select 'D' from t where D = 1)
     ) t
```

As a note:  I hope you have other columns that you can include in the output.  SQL tables are, by definition, not ordered.  So, you really have no idea in your example of the original source for any given value.

Comment: Yes, I have other columns to order the data. I just provided the relevant portion for simplicity's sake. This worked like a charm. Thank you!